# Locus of complex number z

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, locus

Let $λ,z_1,z_2,z_3 ∈ \mathbb{C}$ (Complex Numbers) are such that

$$\frac{z_3-z_1}{z_2-z_1} = \lambda.$$

Now if $$λ=e^{it}$$ where  $t ∈ \mathbb{R}$ and $z_2, z_3$ are fixed, then what will be the locus of $z_1$.

NOTE: I am considering complex numbers $z_1, z_2, z_3$ as points on the Argand's Plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, $\dfrac{z_3-z_1}{z_2-z_1}$ is a complex number then it can be expressed as \begin{align*} 
\dfrac{z_3-z_1}{z_2-z_1}=\left|\dfrac{z_3-z_1}{z_2-z_1}\right|e^{i\phi}=\dfrac{|\vec{AC}|}{|\vec{AB}|}e^{i\phi} \hspace{1cm}...... (1)
\end{align*}
where we have assumed that, $|z_3-z_1|$ is the distance between point $z_3$ and $z_1$ similarly $|z_2-z_1|$ is defined and named as $AC$ & $AB$ respectively. $\phi$ is the argument of the complex number $\dfrac{z_3-z_1}{z_2-z_1}$. But it will be easy if we consider $\phi$ as the angle between the vector $\vec{AC}$ and $\vec{AB}$. It is given that $$\dfrac{z_3-z_1}{z_2-z_1}=\lambda=e^{it}$$ hence we can say $|\vec{AC}|=|\vec{AB}|$. It means $z_1$ moves in such a way that $t$ is the angle between  $z_3-z_1$ and $z_2-z_1$ and the distance between $z_3-z_1$ and $z_2-z_1$ is equal. Geometrically it is the perpendicular bisector of the line joining $z_3$ and $z_2$. Hence locus of the equation $\dfrac{z_3-z_1}{z_2-z_1}=e^{it}$ is a straight line.

Comment: I get that |z3-z1|=|z2-z1|, but I don't think every point on perpendicular bisector will satisfy the condition of having constant angle t between z3-z1 and z2-z1.

Comment: Angle is variable. Isn't it?

Comment: If t is fixed then it is impossible for z_1 to move in the plane of the paper. In that case, you can imagine a circle perpendicular to the plane of the paper whose center lies on the line joining z_3 and z_2.

Comment: Sorry, t is variable. You are correct

Comment: The locus should be perpendicular bisector.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you try the algebraic way as @Learn'd_Astronomer suggested in the above comment?

Comment: Yes, but it was getting a bit long and complicated

Comment: I request you to complete that and share it with me. Will you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122568/discussion-between-amaan-and-infinitecool23).